# Error with MySQL 5 using JOIN and UNION

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have many MySQL statements that are running under MySQL 4, but not MySQL 5. These are statements that combine a UNION and a JOIN.

Trying to simplify the MySQL statement I came to the following that runs under MySQL 4 but not MySQL 5:

```
SELECT
  bteamres.rank AS `rank`
FROM
  bteamres
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (btourn AS tourn) ON (bteamres.tourncode=tourn.tourncode)
WHERE
  (bteamres.nofivb1=100427)

UNION

SELECT
  bteamres.rank AS `rank`
FROM
  bteamres
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (btourn AS tourn) ON (bteamres.tourncode=tourn.tourncode)
WHERE
  (BTEAMRES.NOFIVB2=100427)
```

The error code I receive is:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON     (bteamres.tourncode=tourn.tourncode)
WHERE
  (BTEAMRES.NOFIVB2=100427)' at line 15
```

If I remove the join, the request is working fine on both MySQL 4 and MySQL 5.
I know that there are some syntax differences between MySQL 4 and MySQL 5, but I can't see how to make this statement work.

Thank you for your help.
Patrick

Comment: Try wrapping `SELECT`s into parentheses: `(SELECT ...) UNION ALL (SELECT ...)` BTW, you don't have to wrap left joined table names into `()`, unless if it's more beautiful for you :)

Comment: None of your parenthesis are necessary. Remove them all to discard a misinterpretation from mysql.

Comment: Does it produce the same error if you change to all lowercase: `bteamres.nofivb2=100427` ?

Comment: bizicop, putting the `SELECT`s into parenthesis doesn't solve the problem

Comment: ypercube, putting the last condition in lowercase doesn't change anything.

Comment: Sebas, the parentheses are here because the original SQL statement is automatically generated. **BUT** removing the parenthesis on the `JOIN`alias (`btourn as tourn`) solves the problem. I will correct the SQL generator to remove these parenthesis. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem are the parens around the `LEFT JOIN`ed table:

- `LEFT JOIN (btourn AS tourn)` triggers error
- `LEFT JOIN  btourn AS tourn` is accepted

You can try it here (I had to wrap the union into a select to avoid sqlfiddle's bugs):
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4885/11

```
SELECT bteamres.rank AS `rank`
FROM      bteamres
LEFT JOIN btourn AS tourn ON bteamres.tourncode=tourn.tourncode
WHERE bteamres.nofivb1=100427

UNION 

SELECT bteamres.rank AS `rank`
FROM      bteamres
LEFT JOIN btourn AS tourn ON bteamres.tourncode=tourn.tourncode
WHERE bteamres.nofivb2=100427
```

Comment: It is quite interesting that you can use the `(btourn AS tourn)` version with a single select.

Comment: Then it must be the famous MySQL "quality".

Comment: @biziclop - what bug with sql fiddle are you referring to?  This version (without the wrapped select) seems to work the same as your version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4885/25

Comment: Hi Jake, I just noticed that sqlfiddle doesn't seem to like unions with selects wrapped into parens: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/988